# Separate projects in same solution - The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core, ssl, restsharp

I am working in visual studio, created 2 separate .NET Core Web Applications in same solution. I am trying to communicate between those 2 application using REST. So one application is trying to hit endpoint from another application using code:

```
// RestRequest.BaseUrl = ... (this code is in constructor)


[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllAsync()
{
   try
   {
       var request = new RestRequest("/api/test123", Method.GET);
       var content = await _restClient.GetAsync<IActionResult>(request);
       return content;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
   }
}
```

This code is throwing an exception at line `var content = await _restClient.GetAsync<IActionResult>(request);` and exception is saying `The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.` Inner exception: `The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot`

I saw one of the suggsted solutions on stackoverflow:

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

but these solutions are not working as well.

I also executed `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` but it didnt help.

I realize the problem is because of https and certificates, so I was wondering how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Will you be deploying to production using self-signed development certificates?

Comment: No, it will be regular certificates signed by one of the trusted certificate authorities @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: There you go, not a problem then - you use a commercial CA _exactly because they're widely trusted_, so this is effectively a non-issue in prod :-)

Comment: I was wondering how to fix the issue on local environment :) @MathiasR.Jessen